# Typescript error when $set on mongodb key value subdocument

Tags: typescript, mongodb, mongodb-query

this is an example record.

```json
{
    _id: ObjectId('63e501cc2054071132171098'),
    name: 'Ricky',
    discriminator: 7706,
    registerTime: ISODate('2023-02-09T14:23:08.159Z'),
    friends: {
        '63e502f4e196ec7c04c4351e': {
            friendId: ObjectId('63e502f4e196ec7c04c4351e'),
            friendshipStatus: null,
            privateChannelId: ObjectId('63e66dd85eb6c3cc248ecc95'),
            active: true
        }
    }
}
```

I want to update the property "friends.63e502f4e196ec7c04c4351e.friendshipStatus" from **null** to **1** without replacing the whole subdocument (**I want to keep "friendId", "privateChannelId" and "active" properties**)

currently I have tried

```js
const friendUpdateResult = await collections.users!.updateOne(
  {
    _id: targetFriend._id,
  },
  {
    $set: {
      [`friends.${currentUser._id.toString()}.friendshipStatus`]: null,
    },
  }
);
```

however "$set" is giving me error

```
Type '{ [x: string]: null; }' is not assignable to type 'Readonly<{ [x: `friends.${string}`]: unknown; [x: `friends.${string}.friendId`]: Friend | undefined; [x: `friends.${string}.friendshipStatus`]: Friend | undefined; [x: `friends.${string}.privateChannelId`]: Friend | undefined; [x: `friends.${string}.active`]: Friend | undefined;.
'string' and '`friends.${string}.friendId`' index signatures are incompatible.
Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'Friend | undefined'.
```

my interface for this collection is

```
interface User {
  name: string;
  discriminator: number;
  registerTime: Date;
  friends: Record<string, Friend>;
}

interface Friend {
  friendId: ObjectId;
  friendshipStatus?: FriendshipEnum | null;
  privateChannelId?: ObjectId;
  active?: boolean;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using dynamic values as field name is considered as anti-pattern and introduces unnecessary complexity to queries. Nevertheless, you can use `$objectToArray` to convert `friends` into an array of k-v pair. Use `$map` to conditionally update the field `friendshipStatus`. Finally, revert back to original form using `$arrayToObject`

```js
db.collection.update({
  _id: ObjectId("63e501cc2054071132171098")
},
[
  {
    $set: {
      friends: {
        "$arrayToObject": {
          "$map": {
            "input": {
              "$objectToArray": "$friends"
            },
            "as": "f",
            "in": {
              "$cond": {
                "if": {
                  "$eq": [
                    "$$f.k",
                    "63e502f4e196ec7c04c4351e"
                  ]
                },
                "then": {
                  "$mergeObjects": [
                    "$$f",
                    {
                      v: {
                        "$mergeObjects": [
                          "$$f.v",
                          {
                            "friendshipStatus": 1
                          }
                        ]
                      }
                    }
                  ]
                },
                "else": "$$f"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/GFnfiiKr4EL)

---

If refactoring the schema is an option, you may consider refactoring your schema like this:

```json
[
  {
    _id: ObjectId("63e501cc2054071132171098"),
    name: "Ricky",
    discriminator: 7706,
    registerTime: ISODate("2023-02-09T14:23:08.159Z"),
    friends: [
      {
        friendId: ObjectId("63e502f4e196ec7c04c4351e"),
        friendshipStatus: null,
        privateChannelId: ObjectId("63e66dd85eb6c3cc248ecc95"),
        active: true
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

which you can index the `friends.friendId` field to improve the performance.

The query can become much simpler:

```js
db.collection.update({
  _id: ObjectId("63e501cc2054071132171098"),
  "friends.friendId": ObjectId("63e502f4e196ec7c04c4351e")
},
{
  $set: {
    "friends.$.friendshipStatus": 1
  }
})
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/RFT_HhSfZzA)

Comment: because I thought direct access base on the key is faster than the array, is there any performance difference? both in mongodb searching and client side searching

Comment: @LucasChan yes, because using dynamic values as field name now involves more operation like converting to array and converting back. You can simply use your `friends.friendId` like [this](https://mongoplayground.net/p/UxnCYecKwJf)

Comment: I mean if there wasn't such problem for typing error, accessing friends['xxx'] is faster than looking up the correct element in the array one by one

Comment: @LucasChan We are only converting it into an array since you set dynamic value as field name, which can be avoided by reusing `friends.friendId` in the new playground in comment. That has the same performance advantage as your approach for setting dynamic field names but can faciliate a much simpler query. In addition, using static field name can support indexing which can receive further performance boost.